# Accessing specific value from Ruby array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have this an array of hashes structured like this

```
[{:payer_id=>1, :price=>20}, {:payer_id=>2, :price=>30}]
```

etc. How can I access the price given a specific `payer_id`? I know this question is basic but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
payers = [{:payer_id=>1, :price=>20}, {:payer_id=>2, :price=>30}]
payer_id = 2

payers.detect { |payer| payer[:payer_id] == payer_id }.try(:[], :price)
# => 30
```

I used [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to get the first payer that matches the id, then get its price. In case, no payer matched, you got `nil` returned so you can use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) to get the price so the code won't raise errors even no payer were found.
*※ `try` is part of ActiveSupport so if you don't use it, just replace `.try(:[], :price)` with `[:price]`.*

Comment: Note that `try` requires ActiveSupport, which the OP may not have.

Comment: @oldergod: After the last edit I'm satisfied with the answer enough for an upvote. By ridding of `#try` method, you rid your code of [chicken typing smell](http://talklikeaduck.denhaven2.com/2007/10/22/chicken-typing-isnt-duck-typing).